# Upload Image from Camera to Server

Tags: android, kotlin, file-upload, retrofit2

here I would like to ask how to properly upload an image taken from the camera to a server through an API that has a MultipartBody request body. I believe I have done everything correctly, but for some reason, an error occurs where the path of the captured photo cannot be found.

**Here's my Homepage code **

```
@Composable
fun Homepage(navController: NavHostController) {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val file = context.createImageFile()
    val uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
        Objects.requireNonNull(context),
        BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", file
    )

    var capturedImageUri by remember {
        mutableStateOf<Uri>(Uri.EMPTY)
    }

    val cameraLauncher =
        rememberLauncherForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.TakePicture()) {
            capturedImageUri = uri
            uploadImage(capturedImageUri)
        }

    val permissionLauncher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
        ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission()
    ) {
        if (it) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Permission Granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            cameraLauncher.launch(uri)
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }

    Scaffold(
        bottomBar = {
            BottomAppBar(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .height(65.dp)
                    .background(Color.White)
                    .clip(RoundedCornerShape(15.dp, 15.dp, 0.dp, 0.dp)),
                cutoutShape = CircleShape,
                backgroundColor = Color(0xff6f7cfc),
                elevation = 22.dp,
            ) {
                BottomNav(navController = navController)
            }
        },
        floatingActionButtonPosition = FabPosition.Center,
        isFloatingActionButtonDocked = true,
        floatingActionButton = {
            FloatingActionButton(
                shape = CircleShape,
                onClick = {
                    val permissionCheckResult =
                        ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                    if (permissionCheckResult == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        cameraLauncher.launch(uri)
                    } else {
                        // Request a permission
                        permissionLauncher.launch(android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                    }
                },
                contentColor = Color.White,
                backgroundColor = Color(0xff6f7cfc),
            ) {
                Icon(imageVector = Icons.Filled.Add, contentDescription = "Add icon")
            }
        }
    ) { innerPadding ->
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(innerPadding)
                .fillMaxSize(),
            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
        ) {
            MyUI()
        }
    }
}
```

**And then this is my CreateImageFile Code**

```
fun Context.createImageFile(): File {
    // Create an image file name
    val timeStamp = SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(Date())
    val imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_"
    val image = File.createTempFile(
        imageFileName, /* prefix */
        ".jpg", /* suffix */
        externalCacheDir      /* directory */
    )
    return image
}
```

**My UploadImage Code**

```
private fun uploadImage(imageUri: Uri) {
    val file = File(imageUri.path)
    val requestBody: RequestBody = file.asRequestBody("image/*".toMediaTypeOrNull())
    val multipartBody = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file", file.name, requestBody)
    RetrofitClient.apiModel.predictImage(multipartBody).enqueue(object : Callback<PredictResponse> {
        override fun onResponse(call: Call<PredictResponse>, response: Response<PredictResponse>) {
            if (response.isSuccessful) {
                Log.e("Predict", "Berhasil: ${response.body()}")
            } else {
                Log.e("Predict", "Error: ${response.body()}")
            }
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<PredictResponse>, t: Throwable) {
            Log.e("Predict", "Error: ${t.message}")
        }
    })
}
```

**My Provider in AndroidManifest and the XML Code**

```
<provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
        </provider>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-cache-path name="my_images" path="/"/>
</paths>
```

So after capturing the image from the camera, I attempt to send it to the server by calling the uploadImage function on the following line of code.
`val cameraLauncher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.TakePicture()) { capturedImageUri = uri uploadImage(capturedImageUri) }`

Then an error like this appears:
**E/Predict: Error: /my_images/JPEG_20230615_094103_5565127161183334739.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory).**
[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5zXi.png)
What could be wrong with my approach? Is there anything that needs to be changed?

Comment: `File(imageUri.path)` Use File.exists() before you try to upload. And see that you have an impossible parth to begin with.